# Problems with CakePHP shell in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cakephp, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, cakephp-bake

could somebody explain why this:

```
sudo Console/cake
```

works when I am inside `path/to/cakeproject/app` while this:

```
sudo cake
```

absolutely does NOT work whe I am inside `path/to/cakeproject/app/Console`?

Actually, understanding this would be simply a first step for me to understand why I can run `sudo Console/cake` when I am in the right directory (app), but I cannot run `sudo cake` anywhere even after modifying the PATH variable following [these steps](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#adding-cake-to-your-system-path). If someone knows any possible causes for this already, please also feel free to share your thoughts.

PS: About when I said "I cannot run `sudo cake` anywhere", this is the error I get:

```
sudo: cake: command not found
```

Comment: Did you reload your .bashrc file after modifying it? (Using `source ~/.bashrc` Or starting a new SSH/terminal session should also do it.

Comment: You should just always call the cake console from the app dir: `Console/cake`. That always just works out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.

You just need to install "php5-cli" to make it works.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Then try again with "cake" in your console.

```
$ cake
```

It should work.

Comment: Just did this and I still can't use it along with sudo (sudo cake) for some reason. Still getting `sudo: cake: command not found`, while sudo Console/cake works perfectly. And most commands I want to run won't work without SU privileges, so this is really a must :(